# A fadeing line in html using css

Tags: html, css, border, line

I want to add this kind of line, or border if it's better to do this as an border to my site,
How can I do that

[image]

Comment: they are talking about something like this on https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/sexy-css3-fading-line/

Comment: Have you tried any code so far, or have any ideas of possible solutions? More details in your question will help others answer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **linear-gradient** css function:

```css
hr {
   height: 2px;
   border: 0;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(65, 191, 255, 0), rgba(65, 191, 255, 1), rgba(65, 191, 255, 0));
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient